# AWS ssh always ask passphrase

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I have a question about the aws ssh issue since I have a private and public subnet in VPC, I created a NAT server in public subnet and plan to use this NAT server to connect to our web server in private subnet, I also use the same key pair, which is AWS console provide, to build up both instance (NAT and web server), when I tried to connect to the NAT with public IP with this key, it works, when I tried to use this NAT server to remote login into webserver, it always ask me a passphrase, I don't know how to find the default passphrase with AWS provide, both instances uses Amazon linux instance as server. I have tried the following things

1. change the authroized_key in NAT server owner ship
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_key
2. Wait over 5 mins to buildup both instances, but it doesn't work
3. Applied all traffic with inbound and outbound, and also security group is

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "tried to use this NAT server to remote login into webserver" ?

Comment: Post the output of ssh with `-v` option.

Comment: The following ssh -v as below

Comment: This is unrelated to EC2, but about ssh key usage and files in general.  You can't log in to A then from there log in to B unless you have a copy of a private key on A that you can use when logging in to B... and you don't.  `authorized_keys` contains *public* keys, not *private*.  Leave it alone.  It's not an identity file, not usable with `-i`.  You "could" put B's private key on A, but you "should" use an SSH tunnel through A to B.  Security groups are unrelated, and the is 0 wait time needed.

Comment: Look at forwarding the ssh agent. Either with a `-A` flag to the ssh client or by adding `ForwardAgent yes` to your `~/.ssh/config` file. Test the forwarding with `ssh-add -l` on the remove shell.

Answer (score 0):

by using putty directly you can't login to private server. You have to login to bastion server and then ssh to private through bastion server. 
And also try to change the key permissions to 400, by using chmod command.

So by using winscp share that pem file to the bastion server and change the permission of file to 400 and then try ssh to private.